# Different results when populating a vector from a stream and a buffer

Tags: c++, c++11, ifstream

I have a binary file that I am loading into a byte vector, and I'm unexpectedly getting different results depending on how I read the file. I suspect that it has something to do with my use of [istream_iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/istream_iterator/), but I would like to better understand what is happening. By way of background, the data being loaded is simply a byte stream. If it matters, and I think it may, the final dozen or so bytes are 0x00.

**Case 1**

```
ifstream is("file.dat", ifstream::binary);
vector<uint8_t> v;
v.assign(istream_iterator<uint8_t>(is), istream_iterator<uint8_t>());
```

**Case 2**

```
ifstream is("file.dat", ifstream::binary);
vector<uint8_t> v;
is.seekg(0, in.end);
int length = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, in.beg);
char* buffer = new char[length];
is.read(buffer, length);
v.assign(buffer, buffer + length);
```

Case 1 results in a smaller vector. The initial data in both vectors are the same, but in Case 1 it is truncated.

Comment: IIRC `istream_iterator` uses a formatted input function. `read` is an unformatted input function. The mode of the stream (binary or text) is only used for some transformations such as `\r\n` to `\n` on Windows, for example.

Comment: Btw it is not necessary to create an array on the heap manually and then copying the contents into the vector. `v.resize(length); is.read(v.data(), length);` will work as well.

Comment: Can you please clarify which vector is shorter? First you say that case 1 is larger, then you say it's truncated.

Comment: Case 2 results in a memory leak

Comment: @MarkB Case 1 is smaller; fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vlad has provided an improved version of Code #1, I'll provide a better Code #2:

```
basic_filebuf<uint8_t> ifb;
ifb.open("file.dat", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);

vector<uint8_t> v;
v.resize(ifb.pubseekoff(0, ios_base::end));
ifb.pubseekpos(0);
ifb.sgetn(&v[0], v.size());
```

The fact is that an `ifstream` is not intended for processing unformatted data, even when `ios_base::binary` is used to open it.  That flag is somewhat misnamed -- it disables newline translations, but it doesn't cause insertion and extraction operations to use binary encodings.

This version should be quite a lot faster, not only because there's less copying when the vector is preallocated, but because filebuf `xsgetn` can be expected to transfer large blocks, whereas iterators access single elements.  Even if there is a buffer used to do large block transfers at the I/O level, the virtual calls per-character imposed by the iterators will kill performance.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. It seems that I've been misusing ifstream this whole time. Also, I profiled both solutions and this solution is super fast.

Comment: Ben, I really like this solution, but alas on my rig (OSX using Xcode and clang-900.0.39.2) I'm greeted with an undefined template `std::__1::codecvt<unsigned char, char, __mbstate_t>` in the constructor of the `basic_filebuf<uint8_t>`. I'm not sure if this is universal or specific to the clang that Apple uses, but it saddens me, as I really like this approach.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I suppose you could work around that by using `basic_filebuf<char>` (aka `filebuf`) and casting `(char*)&v[0]` in the `sgetn` call.  `signed char` and `unsigned char` are guaranteed to be layout-compatible with unqualified `char`.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
ifstream is("file.dat", ifstream::binary);
vector<uint8_t> v;
v.assign(istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

As for istream_iterator then it uses operator >>.

Comment: In reality wouldn't it be better to use a `filebuf`, and not have any streams at all? (seeing as how streams are completely pointless for unformatted data)

Comment: @Ben Voigt He need to fill a vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: What does that have to do with whether the `filebuf` is wrapped in a `ifstream`?

Comment: @Ben Voigt In any case he needs to use some iterators does not he?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Yes, and `istreambuf_iterator` can be constructed from a `filebuf`, since that is a `streambuf`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Yes, it can. At least there is such a constructor.